# Open a existing project after installing IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a existing project folder /mnt/proj_1 with a proj_1.iml, a hidden directory .idea, and Java source files. After I install IntelliJ IDEA, I did the following:

```
$ cd /mnt/proj_1
$ /apps/idea/bin/idea.sh &
```

It did not open the project automatically. I used File > Open, and click proj_1.iml. It opened the file, not the project.

How can I open the folder as project?

Comment: Try using File | Open and select the directory of the project. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using File | Open and select the directory of the project.